# Class NativeInterface

Tags: java, class, user-interface

I'm kinda new at java programming and I had a question about Class `NativeInterface`. What is it? I know it is such a vague question but what can you do with methods like `NativeInterface.open()` and `.close()`?

Comment: Which `NativeInterface` class are you referring to? I don't see it in the standard-library Javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a programming framework that enables Java code running in a Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to call and be called by native applications (programs specific to a hardware and operating system platform) and libraries written in other languages such as C, C++ and assembly. 
JNI enables programmers to write native methods to handle situations when an application cannot be written entirely in the Java programming language, e.g. when the standard Java class library does not support the platform-specific features or program library. It is also used to modify an existing application—written in another programming language—to be accessible to Java applications. Many of the standard library classes depend on JNI to provide functionality to the developer and the user, e.g. file I/O and sound capabilities. Including performance- and platform-sensitive API implementations in the standard library allows all Java applications to access this functionality in a safe and platform-independent manner. While using JNI's you have tto be careful because, even subtle errors in the use of JNI can destabilize the entire JVM in ways that are very difficult to reproduce and debug.